# How to paint a custom message on an empty listview control

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have attempted to write a custom class that inherits the ListView control.  So far I have added an OnDrawItem, OnDrawSubItem and OnDrawColumnHeader event which has allowed me to bypass the standard windows drawing to do some custom stuff.

My control is nearly 100% of what I am trying to achieve, however, the last part of it is to add a custom message to an empty ListView control - this is the bit I'm struggling with.  Reading up as much as I can it sounds like I need to add a procedure to capture the NM_CUSTOMDRAW event and do some painting myself (I could be wrong).  Basically, as soon as I try and paint the background, it turns off all the painting for the list items.

As I am not very familiar with this, is someone able to provide a small example or provide a link to some information that might be able to step this out for me.

I have added a **'Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)'** call to capture the WM_NOTIFY message but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction.

I am hoping to simply print a custom message on the background (when empty) without affecting any of the other drawing of the control.

Is this possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You are not heading in the right direction.  A trivial solution is to put a label on top of the listview and set its Visible property to True if the listview is empty.

Comment: there is also an `OnPaintBackground` (and `OnPaint`) where you might be able to do what you want.  `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` is not an event and not a message, but the lParam portion which is a pointer to a `NMLVCUSTOMDRAW` structure.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix.  Do you mind elaborating on that a bit more please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the `WndProc` method and check for `WM_PAINT` message.

```
Public Class UIListView
    Inherits ListView

    Private Sub WmPaint(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Const text As String = "ListView is empty..."
        Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
            Using f As New StringFormat()
                Using b As New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor)
                    f.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    f.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    g.DrawString(text, Me.Font, b, Me.DisplayRectangle, f)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If ((m.Msg = WM_PAINT) AndAlso (Me.Items.Count = 0)) Then
            Me.WmPaint(m)
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Const WM_PAINT As Integer = 15

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn...that worked exactly how I wanted.  The only issues with this now is 1) The designer view goes really screwy when working with the listview and 2) It doesn't paint the column headers initially until I move the window and then they show up. Other than that, works great!

Comment: @user2185200 Ahh.. I didn't test with columns. I've made some minor changes. Please see my edit.